# How to use RewriteRule to handle both HTTP and HTTPS access

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Here is an htaccess file that makes sure that www is on every entry into the site:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine until the site is accessed as 
    "HTTPS://mysite.com", 
because it then gets rewritten as 
    "HTTP://mysite.com"

How can I rework this htaccess file to work for BOTH http and https situations? Some of the pages on the site are designed to be HTTP, while others are designed to work only in HTTPS. I am not an expert on Mod_rewrite, and I have been really struggling with this. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Some of the htacesss syntaxes are really arcane. I appreciate it.